# Php loop Ajax array in mysql

Tags: php, arrays, json, ajax, foreach

I need to do a report sing php & pdf based on another coder's(asp) data in mysql.

```
$Mysqldata_Field1:[{"name":"alex","age":"30","pic":"filename.ext"}, {"name":"alice","age":"29","pic":"filename.ext"}]
```

I need to extract all the "pic" value from the array above which is stored in mysql.

What is the best approach?
I have tried this

```
$img=json_decode($Mysqldata_Field1,true);
foreach($img as $item=>$pic)
{
   $images .= $pic["pic"].",";
}
```

But I'm getting error:
Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: try to var_dump $img

Comment: The issue might be with `$Mysqldata_Field1`. This seems to work if that is a string.

Comment: So I have to treat it as string instead of array?

Comment: var_dump showed that most of the data wasnt complete array.
therefore the array did not work.
so managed to get those array fixed in db then the script worked .. thank you for your suggestion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to both the suggestion.
var_dump showed that the $mysqldata_Field1 contains both array for some records and some strings (incomplete array).

managed to correct those data entry to make a complete array, then the script worked.

this time its not the code issue, its the data entry.